# PostgreSQL table describe output, what does it mean?

Tags: postgresql

So I get output like this when I do a table describe on a PostgreSQL table.

2, module, varchar, -1, 68, t

I'm guessing 2 is the column number, "module" is the column name, varchar is the datatype, 68 is the length, t is nullable.

Is this correct and what does the -1 signify?

Thanks

Comment: This is not the output you get from psql. Which tool are you using to do the "describe"

Comment: Looks like the output of `pg_meta_data()`, but not quite. Post the code for this "describe".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-1 is the "typmod" (type modifier).  For most types, -1 means default or unspecified.  For varchar, specifically, -1 means unlimited length.